# Span and inner product

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that:

1. $\{||Au||: u \in U\}$ is an unbounded set.

I try to use the definition of the norm and expand $||Au||$ to be a sum of complicated terms, and then I try to claim that the sum is bounded as it is just a finite sum of real numbers. I did not use that fact that $u$ is a unit vector. Is this fine?

For 2, I don't know what to do after I expand the inner products.

Comment: The "complicated" sum gives the value of $\|Au\|$ for a particular vector $u$, so yes, this is a finite real number. But a set of finite real numbers is not necessarily bounded: you need to find a constant $B$ so that $\|Au\| < B$ for every unit vector $u$.

Comment: $10^n + 10^n$ is a finite sum of real numbers... so, is $10^n+10^n$ bounded?

Answer (score 0):

1. Put $A = (a_{ij})$ then you write down the expression of each entry of $Ax,$ you will find that this vector is bounded. Hint: consider the maximal modulus of the entries of $A$ and make some estimates.
2. Since $<Ax, x> = \frac{1}{2}<(A+A^T)x,x>,$ we can suppose $A$ is symmetric, i.e. $A = A^T.$

Then $A$ is orthogonally diagonalisable, i.e., there exists $Q$ orthogonal matrix such that $Q^TAQ$ is diagonal. Put $x = Qx'$ and $y = Qy'.$

Then $x^TAx = x'^T Q^TAQx' = \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i x_i'^2$ where $\lambda_i$ are all eigenvalues of $A$ and $x_i'$ are coordinates of $x'.$

Remark that $\|x-y\| = \|x'-y'\|.$ The remaining part is simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an answer to 1, as @Pedro has already given a full answer to 2.

If $u=(u_1,\dots,u_n)\in U$ and $A=(a_{jk})_{j,k=1}^n$, then

$$\lVert Au\rVert=\left\lVert\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_{1k}u_k,\dots,\sum_{k=1}^na_{nk}u_k\right)\right\rVert=\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_{jk}u_k\right)^2}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_{jk}^2\right)\underbrace{\left(\sum_{m=1}^nu_m^2\right)}_{=1}}=\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^na_{jk}^2},$$

where the inequality is just Cauchy-Schwarz. Since the RHS is just a constant independent of $u$, it follows that $u\mapsto\lVert Au\rVert$ is bounded on $U$.